# How to copy xcode app to iphone device using ssh without IDP

Tags: ios, xcode, ssh, xcode3.2, iphone-developer-program

Without iPhone Developer Program, can we push the App to Iphone Device, bypassing code signing and provisoning the device.

I need this as part of testing my test app.
I do have a Jailbroken Iphone 3.1.3, Xcode 3.2.5, SDK 4.1

Pls help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't to do kind of automatic testing with something like hudson/jenkins it's basically the only way of automating deployment on physical iOS device (you can also use the iOS simulator).

You can install openssh from cydia and do a normal scp to the application folder (/Applications).

check [this](http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/how-to-install-apps-on-devices-without-certificate/).

Okay?

Comment: I did install openssh into my iphone, i did
ssh root@IP , but could not find Applications folder..

Can you brief me on step- by-step procedure.

And also, im getting code sign error / no provisioned ios device found error, while building for Device..

Can you address this issue too. pls....

Comment: check this (also added to the answer): http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/how-to-install-apps-on-devices-without-certificate/